# How to fix having two parents in git

Tags: git, git-merge

I was messing with my source control plugin (TortoiseGit) and ended up having two heads now. When I commit I get the message that there are difference with two parents. Before making things even worse, how to merge these two parents back to one?

Me and others already made several commits (and pushes) before I detected this issue.

Comment: Maybe with `git reflog` you may fix your issues.

Comment: Try to compare the contents of `.git/HEAD` and `.git/ORIG_HEAD`, with a bit of luck, your original (in fact : previous) HEAD still points to a sane situation.

Comment: @RomainVALERI no, these are references to two recent heads. the situation is there for over two weeks now.

Comment: What is the exact command you're using to commit, and what is the exact output of that command?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger just the commit method from turtoise git.

Answer (score 0):

In that instance, it is best to fall back to the Git command line, and have a look at:

- `git status`
- `git branch -avv`
- `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches --all`

You should see all branches HEAD and can see if you need to merge one into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive rebase from a commit before the split worked for me. (IntelliJ IDEA and presumably a few other programs for version control visually shows how the branches split and merge back together)